# Can not uninstall facebook

Tags: facebook

I have a brand new Qmobile 400 dual sim tab with jelly bean android 4.2.2 version. 
Downloaded facebook from play store but now unable to uninstall it. The message say" delete all the updates on this device" but not the app itself. How do I uninstall it???

Comment: Are you sure the facebook app wasn't installed when you first bought the phone? there is a chance it was a system app and you are unable to uninstall it but you can remove all updates.

Comment: As *Tom* suspected, this seems to be a system app which you can't uninstall but only disable as a normal user. However, if you decide to root the device then you may very well uninstall any app.

Comment: no the app was installed by me after i bought the device...it also didnt create any shortcuts like others..

Answer (score -1):

You can install [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en), an app that allows you to uninstall any and all applications, system included.

Comment: Link2SD additionally requires root permission to do system app removal, a condition unstated in the OP's question, and, not a clear assumption.

Comment: @wbogacz True. I assumed root access.

Comment: @user110507 It would be much better if you provide a brief description of this app. You may quote it directly.